# Difference between 1.3.2 meaningful sequence and 2.4.3 Focus order

Tags: accessibility

I want to know the difference between the wcag 2.1 guideline meaningful sequence and focus order.

My understanding is that both guideline is saying that Tab order should be meaningful and sequential.
in meaningful sequce , we use the test approach linear navigation, use arrows and just observe the paragraph are reading line by line, abbreviation, ph no, user address, tables column value etc.

whereas in focus order, we check using TAB key to observe the input field, links, are going in a sequential order..

please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in understanding that both guidelines, 1.3.2 Meaningful Sequence and 2.4.3 Focus Order, are related to the order of elements in a web page or application. However, there are some differences between them.

Guideline 1.3.2 Meaningful Sequence is focused on the visual order of content on a page, whereas Guideline 2.4.3 Focus Order is focused on the tab order of interactive elements, such as links and form fields.

In other words, Guideline 1.3.2 is concerned with ensuring that the content on the page flows logically and can be understood by users who are navigating it visually. This includes considerations like the order of headings, paragraphs, and lists.

On the other hand, Guideline 2.4.3 is concerned with ensuring that users can navigate interactive elements on the page using the keyboard alone, without relying on a mouse or other pointing device. This includes considerations like the order in which form fields are focused when the user presses the Tab key, as well as ensuring that links and buttons are reachable and usable via keyboard input.

To summarise, while both guidelines are related to the order of elements on a web page or application, they have slightly different focuses and address different aspects of accessibility.